# Customize menus

Tags: routes

I would like to customize the main menu of my website by assign different classes to every li item in the list. I have a standard number of elements in menu. I have the following code in the page.tpl.php file.

```
$menu_header = menu_navigation_links('main-menu');
print theme('links__main_menu', array('links' => $menu_header, 'attributes' => array('class' => ''))); ?>
```

In the template.tpl.php file I have the following function:

```
function newtheme_menu_link(array $variables) {
  $element  = $variables['element'];
  $menuName = $variables['element']["#original_link"]["menu_name"];

  if (strcmp($menuName,"main-menu") == 0) {
    $element['#attributes']['class'][] = 'menu-' . $element['#original_link']['mlid'];
    if ($element['#below']) {
      $sub_menu = drupal_render($element['#below']);
    }
    $output = l($element['#title'], $element['#href'], $element['#localized_options']);

    return '<li' . drupal_attributes($element['#attributes']) . '>' . $output . $sub_menu . "</li>\n";
  }
}
```

It should at least append mlid to every `<li>` element, but it does not work.

How can I have different classes based on the position of the `<li>` element?

Comment: I really hate drupal....

Comment: You are calling `theme('links__main_menu')`, and you are showing the code of a different theme function. Why?

Comment: because the docs says that theme($hook, $variables = array()) and in the name of the override function must be [theme_name]_menu_lin()....

Comment: `newtheme_menu_link()` doesn't override `theme_links__main_menu()`, or `theme_links()`.

Comment: Look : Fatal error: Cannot redeclare theme_links() that's the error i get if i change the name as you said... and with theme_links__main_menu still not working...

Comment: by writing var_dump($menuName); in newtheme_menu_link(array $variables) i get only the dump from administration menu , not for main_menu as i want to ... I still hate drupal...

Comment: `theme_links()` is a function already defined from Drupal. A theme would implement `mytheme_links()`. (Replace `mytheme` with the name of the theme.)

Comment: i get a lot of undefined indexes because theme_links() does not accept menu item as parameters...

Comment: I am not clear in what I am saying. You are showing two different pieces of code that are not related to each other, which means `theme('links__main_menu')` doesn't call `newtheme_menu_link()`. You say it doesn't work, but that is what I would expect, for the simple fact your function is not called from a call to `theme('links__main_menu')`, or `theme('links')`.

Comment: all i want to do is to add different classes to li elements from main-menu , how could i do it ?

Comment: The function from my question dumps only variables from administrative panel...